# Prove that if $f^{(k)}(f^{-1}(x))$ exists, and is nonzero, then $(f^{-1})^{(k)}(x)$ exists.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, inverse-function

I think I found an error and just want to confirm.

This is from Calculus by Michael Spivak, 3rd edition, Chapter 12 (Inverse Functions), problem 21.

> 12-21. Prove that if $f^{(k)}(f^{-1}(x))$ exists, and is nonzero, then $(f^{-1})^{(k)}(x)$ exists.

This appears to be false. For example, take $f(x) = x^3$.

In this case
$$f^{-1}(x) = x^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
$$f(0) = f^{-1}(0) = 0$$
$$f^{(3)}(0) = 6$$

If the statement is true, $(f^{-1})^{(3)}(0)$ would exist. However, $(f^{-1})'(0)$ doesn't exist (because $f'(0) = 0$) so higher order derivatives cannot.

I think the question should instead say "Prove that if $f^{(k)}(f^{-1}(x))$ exists, and $f'(f^{-1}(x))$ is nonzero, then $(f^{-1})^{(k)}(x)$ exists.

Does that sound about right to y'all?

**Edit:** As discussed with Paul Frost, the revised version of the statement

> Prove that if $f^{(k)}(f^{-1}(x))$ exists, and $f'(f^{-1}(x))$ is nonzero, then $(f^{-1})^{(k)}(x)$ exists

is missing one other thing.

We need $f$ to be one-one on some interval containing $f^{-1}(x)$.

For cases $k\geq 2$, $f$ one-one is implied by $f'(f^{-1}(x))≠0$, and the existence of $″(f^{-1}(x))$ (which gives us the existence of $f'$ for all points in some interval containing $f^{-1}(x)$ and continuity of $f'$ at $f^{-1}(x)$). We can prove the (corrected) statement for $k≥2$. However, we don't know if $f$ is one-one for the case $k=1$. As problem 11-63 shows, $f'(f^{-1}(x))\neq 0$ by itself isn't enough to guarantee $f$ is increasing (or decreasing) over some interval containing $f^{-1}(x)$

But that's ok. The higher derivative cases are the ones we're interested in anyway, so we can take $k = 2$ as the base case and use induction from there.

The *corrected* corrected statement reads:
"Prove that if $f^{(k)}(f^{-1}(x))$ exists, and $f'(f^{-1}(x))$ is nonzero, then $(f^{-1})^{(k)}(x)$ exists for all $k\geq 2$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$

For the $k=1$ case, we have theorem 12-5.

Comment: I think your counterexample is correct, and wikipedia includes a statement that sounds like your formulation (see 3rd par): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statement

Comment: Ah, thank you preferred. The 3rd para of that says "...$k$-th differentiable, with nonzero derivative at the point $a$..." Do you think by "nonzero derivative" it means only $f'(a)$, the first derivative? Or is is saying all of the higher order derivatives must be $\neq 0$? I suspect the former.

Comment: The sentence certainly appears to suggest just the first derivative - I'm not sure about the proof.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I can prove the corrected version of the statement by postulating a very generalized form for the $k$-th derivative of $f^{-1}$ and using induction. Glad I didn't bang my head too hard on trying to prove the false statement! This question is marked with a * in the book to indicate it's challenging. I imagine more than a few poor souls have concluded it was "too hard for them". It's too hard for anyone, as it's not true!

Comment: This problem was removed from the 4th edition.

Comment: @GEdgar heh, that's too bad. It's a nice result, once it's rephrased to actually be possible :)

Comment: Actually, @GEdgar is wrong. It was corrected and moved to be 12.12. It now states: Prove that if $f'(f^{-1}(x))\ne 0$ and $f^{(k)}(f^{-1}(x))$ exists, then $(f^{-1})^{(k)}(x)$ exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your counterexample is correct; Spivak seems to be a bit unattentive. He also does not say anything about $f$ except that $f^{(k)}(f^{-1}(x_0))$ exists (and is $\ne 0$, which you have shown to be inadequate). The existence of $f^{(k)}(f^{-1}(x_0))$ means more precisely that (a) there is an open neigborhood $U$ of $f^{-1}(x_0)$ on which $f$ is $(k-1)$-times differentiable, and (b) $f^{(k)}(f^{-1}(x_0))$ exists.

In Theorems 12.4 and 12.5 Spivak states for an injective function $f$ which is differentiable at $f^{-1}(x_0)$:

1. If $f'(f^{-1}(x_0)) = 0$, then $f^{-1}$ is not differentiable at $x_0$.
2. If $f'(f^{-1}(x_0)) \ne 0$, then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $(f^{-1})'(x_0) = \dfrac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x_0))}$.

Thus the *minimal requirement* for the existence of $(f^{-1})'(x_0)$, and hence for the existence of $(f^{-1})^{(k)}(x_0)$ for some $k \ge 1$, is
$$f'(f^{-1}(x_0)) \ne 0 \tag{1}.$$

Now assume that $f^{(k)}(f^{-1}(x_0))$ exists (with any value of $f^{(k)}(f^{-1}(x_0))$) and $(1)$ is satisfied. We shall (a) construct an open neigborhood $V$ of $x_0$ such that $f^{-1}$ is $(k-1)$-times differentiable on $V$ (b) show that $(f^{-1})^{(k)}(x_0))$ exists.

For $k = 1$ nothing remains to do; 2. applies. We now consider $k > 1$.

Since $f''(f^{-1}(x_0))$ exists, $f'$ is continuous at $f^{-1}(x_0)$, thus $f'(y) \ne 0$ for all $y$ in some open neigborhood $U' \subset U$ of $f^{-1}(x_0)$. For $x \in V = f(U')$ we have $f^{-1}(x) \in U'$, thus by 2. $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $x$ with derivative  $(f^{-1})'(x) =  \dfrac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$. Clearly $x_0 = f(f^{-1}(x_0)) \in V$. Since $f^{-1}$ is continuous (Theorem 12.3), $V = f(U') = (f^{-1})^{-1}(U')$ is open. Thus $V$ is an open neigborhood of $x_0$.

We shall now show by induction on $r$ that $(f^{-1})^{(r)}(x_0)$ exists on $V$ for all $r < k$. The base case $r=1$ has been treated above. Let us now consider $r=2$, the details of the general case are left to you.

Quotient rule and chain rule show that $(f^{-1})''(x)$ exists for all $x \in V$, where
$$(f^{-1})''(x) = -\dfrac{f''(f^{-1}(x))}{(f'(f^{-1}(x)))^3} .$$
Induction produces for all $x \in V$ a formula for $(f^{-1})^{(r)}(x)$ as a fraction whose denominator is a power of $f'(f^{-1}(x))$ and whose nominator has summands which are products of powers of derivatives $f^{(i)}(f^{-1}(x))$ with $i = 1,\ldots,r$.

This shows that  $(f^{-1})^{(k-1)}(x_0)$ exists on $V$. Clearly we can once more differentiate at $x_0$.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I think Spivak might be missing something else.  We need $f$ to be one-one on some interval containing $x_0$. For cases $k \geq 2$, $f$ one-one is implied by $f'(x_0) \neq 0$, and the existence of $f''(x_0)$ (which gives us the existence of $f'$ in some interval containing $x_0$ and continuity of $f'$ at $x_0$). We can prove the (corrected) statement for $k \geq 2$. However, we don't know if $f$ is one-one for the case $k = 1$. Perhaps Spivak meant for us to assume the statement applied to all $x$ in some interval.

Comment: As problem 12-63 shows, $f'(x_0) \neq 0$ isn't enough to guarantee $f$ is increasing (or decreasing) over some interval containing $x_0$.

Comment: @Ben In chapter 12 Spivak considers only injective $f$, thus we may take that for granted. Otherwise the notation $f^{-1}$ would not make sense (or would need additional explanation in the sense that $f$ is injective on some interval $J$ and $x_0 \in f(J)$).

Comment: Not sure I agree. For example, problem 12-12 involves finding the intervals upon which a non-injective(?) function is can be made injective. (Sorry if I'm not saying it right). In other problems he says explicitly when a function is one-one. Not a big deal though. It's cool that the higher order derivative cases work without this. We can live without the $k=1$ case, as theorem 12-5 has that covered!

Comment: Spivak defines $f^{-1}$ to be the set of all pairs $(a,b)$ for which the pair $(b,a)$ is in $f$. He says, "It is popular to abstain from this procedure unless $f$ is one-one, but there is no particular reason to do so..." and his first theorem of the chapter 12-1 states "$f^{-1}$ is a function if and only if $f$ in one-one." So in our problem, if $f$ is non-injective, $f^{-1}$ makes sense, but (f^{-1})^{(k)} does not...

Comment: I hesitate to add $f$ one-one as an assumption however. Existence of (f^{-1})^{(k)} is what we're trying to prove, and it turns out we don't need to assume $f$ is one-one for cases $k \geq 2$ (and those are the cool cases anyway!).

Comment: Oh, I see now I've been wrongly using $x_0$ to refer to the $f$ point and not the $f^{-1}$ point as you originally specified. Sorry if that was confusing! Happily you understood my argument despite my muddling it.

Comment: @Ben You are right, for each $f$ you can define $f^{-1}$ as a "set-valued function". It may a philosophical discussion, but writing $f^{(k)}(f^{-1}(x))$ only makes sense if $f^{-1}$ is a function, i.e. if $f$ injective. An alternative approach would be this: Consider $y_0$ such that $f^{(k)}(y_0)$ exists and $f'(y_0) \ne 0$. Then, if $k > 1$, we know that $f'$ exists on some open neighorhood $U$ of $y_0$ and is continuous at $y_0$. Hence $f$ is injective on some (possibly smaller) open neighorhood $U_1$ of $y_0$ so that

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is defined as an ordinary function $f(U_1) \to U_1$, where $f(U_1)$ is an open neigborhood of $x_0 = f(y_0)$. In case $k=1$ we cannot conclude from $f'(y_0)$ exists and $f'(y_0) \ne 0$ that $f^{-1}$ exists in an open neigborhood of $x_0 = f(y_0)$.

Comment: PF:"we know that ′ exists on some open neighorhood  of 0 and is continuous at 0. Hence  is injective"  B:" one-one is implied by $′(x_0)≠0$, and the existence of ″(0) (which gives us the existence of ′ in some interval containing $x_0$ and continuity of ′ at $x_0$)"   We agree! (forgive the continued misuse of $x_0$. As it's a quote, I didn't want to confuse things further by fixing it.)

Comment: Sorry for the late comment: Could you please explain why $V_1=f(U_1)$ is valid? Although I agree that $f'(y) \neq 0$ for some open neighborhood $U_1$ around $f^{-1}(x_0)$, I do not think that means that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable for any $x \in V_1$. The $U_1$ claim means for any $y \in (f^{-1}(x_0)-\delta,f^{-1}(x_0)+\delta): f'(y) \neq 0$. This is quite different than if $U_1=(f^{-1}(x_0-\delta)),f^{-1}(x_0+\delta))$, right? I feel like your $V_1$ statement would amount to interpreting $U_1$ as the latter case, rather than the former case, which I think is incorrect.

Comment: However, given that $[f^{-1}]'(x_0) \neq 0$ (because we were told that $f'(f^{-1}(x_0)) \neq 0$ and exists $\in \mathbb R$), we know that $f^{-1}(x_0)$ is not a maximum or a minimum. Given that $f^{-1}$ is a continuous function (because $f$ is a continuous function), I think this would mean that either $(f^{-1}(x_0-\delta),f^{-1}(x_0+\delta)) \subseteq (f^{-1}(x_0)-\delta,f^{-1}+\delta)$ or $(f^{-1}(x_0)-\delta,f^{-1}+\delta) \subseteq (f^{-1}(x_0-\delta),f^{-1}(x_0+\delta))$. So we could always define some smaller $U_2$ to capture this.

Comment: @S.Cramer In fact my proof had a gap; I claimed that $f(U_1)$ is open. See my update which (hopefully) settles this point.

Comment: Thank you for the corrections: a quick clarification, if you would. In general, if I know that $A$ is an open neighborhood about some point $x_0$, and $A \subset B$, I should **not** say that $B$ is an open neighborhood of $x_0$. Rather, I should say that $B$ contains an open neighborhood of $x_0$. My point is that $B$ may contain elements that are not contiguous with $A$'s boundaries. So, for your case, when you write $V \subset f(U')=W$, this is not showing that "W is an open neighborhood of $x_0$". Rather, it is simply showing that $W$ contains an open neighborhood of $x_0$. Is this right?

Comment: @S.Cramer You are right, I did not say that $W$ is an open open neighborhood of $x_0$, but that $W$ contains an open neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$. Anyway, this step was unnecessary. See my recent update.

Comment: Good to know. I was commenting on this line from your most recently updated post: "Clearly $x_0 \in W$, but we do not know whether $W$ is an open neighborhood of $x_0$".